# UTL_FILE.FOPEN() procedure not accepting path for directory in oracle 12c database?

Tags: oracle, unix, plsql

Below code is working perfectly in oracle 10g database

```
 DECLARE
 g_file_handle     UTL_FILE.FILE_TYPE;
 g_dir     varchar2(100);
 BEGIN    
 g_dir :=     Scamp_Utils.getutlfiledir;
 DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (g_dir);
 g_file_handle := UTL_FILE.FOPEN (g_dir, 'qwe.txt', 'W', 32767);
 UTL_FILE.PUT_LINE (g_file_handle, 'BEGINDATA');
 UTL_FILE.FCLOSE (g_file_handle);
 COMMIT;
 END;
 /
```

Here `Scamp_Utils.getutlfiledir` is a function which returns the path defined in `utl_file_dir`.
But same code doesn't work in `oracle 12c database`. I'm getting an error:

> ORA-29280: invalid directory path 
>   ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_FILE", line 41 
>   ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_FILE", line 478 
>   ORA-06512: at line 7

I have already provided `rwx` permission to all at the OS level. I'm still getting this error. I can use the oracle logical directory but I don't want to change code. What should I do here?

Comment: did you create oracle directory [how to create dir](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/Oracle_directory)?

Comment: Display the return value from the function. I am sure the path returned from the function is not correct

Comment: As I said it is working fine in oracle 10g. DBMS output : /appl/flstadm/utl_files/wlsbb01 . This path exists in DB server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oracle has two option to declare a directory for `utl_file`.

```
 1. Change `utl_file_dir='/appl/flstadm/utl_files/wlsbb01'` in INIT.ORA  file and restart DB. This solution is not recommended and deprecated. 

 2. Create directory object in DB.
CREATE OR REPLACE DIRECTORY my_dir AS '/appl/flstadm/utl_files/wlsbb01';
GRANT read, write ON DIRECTORY my_dir TO your_user;

g_file_handle := UTL_FILE.FOPEN ('my_dir', 'qwe.txt', 'W', 32767);
```

Have you added your path to init.ora?

Comment: Yes, I did. SQL> select VALUE from v$parameter where NAME = 'utl_file_dir'; VALUE
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
/var/opt/oracle, /tmp, /appl/flstadm/utl_files, /appl/flstadm/utl_files/wlsbb01

Comment: I will go for 2nd option i.e. using oracle directory only after I am sure that 1st option is not going to work. Since 1st option is working in oracle 10g, but not working in oracle 12c, does that mean oracle 12c does not support it anymore?

Comment: Ok. What command you used to set the parameter?
`alter system set utl_file_dir='/path1, /path2, /path3' scope = spfile;` - wrong


`alter system set utl_file_dir='/path1','/path2','/path3' scope = spfile; ` ok.

Comment: [oracle 12c](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/u_file.htm#ARPLS70897) - _In the past, accessible directories for the UTL_FILE functions were specified in the initialization file using the UTL_FILE_DIR parameter. However, UTL_FILE_DIR access is no longer recommended_

Comment: Thanks Arkadiusz, I was giving path incorrectly in alter system set. It is working fine now.